# f:setPropertyActionListener not working

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I am using richfaces datatable.

To edit  the rich:datatable , i used following lines

```
<a4j:commandLink 
    styleClass="no-decor" 
    reRender="machineDisplayTable"
    value="edit"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('editMyMachinePanel')}.show()">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
        target="#{machineTable.myMachineToEdit}"
        value="#{Machine}"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

where "machineDisplayTable" is id for datatable, "editMyMachinePanel" is rich:modalpanel, "machineTable" is bean class and "myMachineToEdit" is class of type machine.

Now, in rich:modelpanel , where i am printing "machineTable.myMachineToEdit.hostname", i am getting nothing. The code for modelpanel as:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="editMyMachinePanel" autosized="true">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{machineTable.myMachineToEdit.hostname}" />
    </f:facet>
    <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('editMyMachinePanel')}.hide(); return false;" />
</rich:modalPanel>
```

It seems that first panel is getting rendered and then value is assigned to machineTable.myMachineToEdit by f:setPropertyActionListener.

Is there anyway i can assign  machineTable.myMachineToEdit first and then render modalpanel.

Two imp site, regarding same is :

http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=dataTableEdit&skin=blueSky

and

http://binamebou.be/phoenix-framework/wiki/index.php5?title=Richfaces_FAQ

One solution is provided in second link (setting action), but is is also not working in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you should reRender the panel when pressing the a4j:commandLink. Not the table.

reRender="editMyMachinePanel"